# Unable to see merge branch option on TFS for a folder

Tags: tfs, merge, branch

General TFS folders in TFS Source control look like below :
[image]

I have a TFS Folder that looks like this (Please notice the red cross at the beginning) :
[image]

I am not sure why I see the red cross. But it doesn't allow me merge or branch.Both options are greyed out for the above folder :

[image]

Any ideas on why I see the Branch and Merge disabled and  why the folder has a cross ? How can I change the folder as a normal folder ? How can I merge & branch ?

Comment: The red X means that the folder has been deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works now. I just got the latest from source control. Looks like one my teammate has made major changes to the project. On getting the latest , I don't see the red cross any more. Also, I see the merge & branch options.